# ProducerTemplate is always null with camel and spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a requirement to integrate **Camel** with **spring-boot**, to achieve same I am using below code to build `ProducerTemplate` for bean integration but `ProducerTemplate` will always NULL.

**Java Code**

```
@RestController
public class TestController implements ProductSummaryApi {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "direct:test")
    ProducerTemplate testRoute;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(){
        System.out.println("Route: " + testRoute);
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Line         `System.out.println("Route: " + testRoute);` prints NULL

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any hint appreciated, why the application is not able to build `ProducerTemplate` object.

Comment: where you write the code? in witch class? can you share full code of class?

Comment: Can you post your class that holds `producerTemplate`?  This information is insufficient.

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

- If you rely on predefined `ProducerTemplate` from spring boot camel, `@Produce` relies on Spring for dependency injection of Producer template. Which means that the service that **autowires** the producer template must register itself as the bean. 
  Check if your service class is annotated with `@Component` or it's sub-types.
- If  you programmatically create `ProducerTemplate` and have associated with a context(assuming you have registered as bean using `@Bean`), use `@Produce(context="contextName1")`.

Check your component scan path. That's mostly your issue.